# How to loop a form to three time in Vuejs

Tags: vuejs2

I am facing an issue where I need to display one select field two times in the form and while saving the form it will save the data in an array.

What I have done is created a form and added a select form and I want it to display two times (two select form) and it will be able to select different values for two select displays

I have created a sandbox [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-wilson-h6q1j?file=/src/App.vue)

Any ideas are much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create new variable to second value with same options as first select input and save it as array.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <b-form-select
      class="mb-2 mr-sm-2 mb-sm-0"
      :options="optQuality"
      v-model="slcQuality"
      @input="changeQuality"
    >
    </b-form-select>
    <div>slcQuality: {{ slcQuality }}</div>
    <b-form-select
      class="mb-2 mr-sm-2 mb-sm-0"
      :options="optQuality"
      v-model="slcQuality2"
      @input="changeQuality"
    >
    </b-form-select>
    <div>slcQuality: {{ slcQuality2 }}</div>
    <div>
      <button @click="submit">Submit</button>
    </div>
    <div>submitted Data: {{ JSON.stringify(submittedData) }}</div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      optQuality: [
        { value: 1, text: "Original" },
        { value: 2, text: "Kw-1" },
        { value: 3, text: "Kw-2" },
      ],
      slcQuality: null,
      slcQuality2: null, // new variable
      submittedData: [],
    };
  },
  methods: {
    changeQuality() {
      console.log("test");
      console.log(this.slcQuality);
    },
    submit() {
      const data = [this.slcQuality, this.slcQuality2]; //save data as array
      this.submittedData = data;
      console.log(data);
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

**EDIT**

To avoid massive code you could use an array of objects as variable or nested array like this, then loop twice in template (nested v-for).

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div v-for="(quality, i) in slcQualities" :key="i">
      <div v-for="(selection, j) in quality.values" :key="j">
        <div>{{ selection.name }}</div>
        <b-form-select
          class="mb-2 mr-sm-2 mb-sm-0"
          :options="quality.options"
          v-model="selection.value"
          @input="changeQuality"
        />
        <div>slcQuality: {{ quality.value }}</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <button @click="submit">Submit</button>
    </div>
    <div>submitted Data: {{ JSON.stringify(submittedData) }}</div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
// array of data
const qualities = [
  {
    options: [
      { value: 1, text: "Original" },
      { value: 2, text: "Kw-1" },
      { value: 3, text: "Kw-2" },
    ],
    values: [
      { name: "Select 1-1", value: null },
      { name: "Select 1-2", value: null },
    ],
  },
  {
    options: [
      { value: 1, text: "Original" },
      { value: 2, text: "Kw-3" },
      { value: 3, text: "Kw-4" },
    ],
    values: [
      { name: "Select 2-1", value: null },
      { name: "Select 2-2", value: null },
    ],
  },
];

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      slcQualities: qualities,
      submittedData: [],
    };
  },
  methods: {
    changeQuality() {
      console.log("test");
      console.log(this.slcQuality);
    },
    submit() {
      const data = this.slcQualities.map((i) => i.values.map((j) => j.value)); //map the values
      this.submittedData = data;
      console.log(data);
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Here's the [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/hardcore-cannon-tugcz?file=/src/components/HelloWorld.vue:0-1151)

Comment: Thank you. Lets say down the line, if I need another 15 dropdowns inside a form and another set of inputs with different values, the code is going to be massive. 
so is there a way to group the 10 or 15 input fields to one and another group with other input fields.?

Comment: You could use nested v-for. I've edited my answer and sandbox too